# How to Receive JSON Response in Swift 3

Tags: json, swift3

I'm having a lot of difficulty trying to figure out the syntax for sending, and receiving JSON with Swift3, when communicating with a server. So far, I have the following code in my Connection class:

```
import Foundation

class Connection: NSObject, GCDAsyncSocketDelegate {

    var socket: GCDAsyncSocket!

    func open(host: String, port: UInt16) {

        print("Attempting connection on Host: \(host) at Port: \(port)")
        socket = GCDAsyncSocket(delegate: self, delegateQueue: DispatchQueue.main)

        do {
            try socket.connect(toHost: host, onPort: port)
        } catch let e {
            print(e)
        }
    }

    func socket(_ socket: GCDAsyncSocket, didConnectToHost host: String, port p: UInt16) {

        print("Connected to \(host) on port \(p)")

        let sendJSON = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: ["NAME":"JERRY","TYPE":"CONNECT"], options: [])

        socket.write(sendJSON!, withTimeout: -1, tag: 0)

        let data = Data()

        //socket.readData(to: data, withTimeout: -1, tag: 1)

        let recJSON = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions()) as! [String : AnyObject]

        socket.readData(to: data, withTimeout: -1, tag: 1)
        let parseJSON = recJSON?["TYPE"]

        print("data: \(data)")
        print("parseJSON: \(parseJSON)")
        print("recJSON: \(recJSON)")
        print("sendJSON: \(sendJSON)")

        socket.disconnect()
        print("Disconnecting")
    }

    func socketDidDisconnect(_ sock: GCDAsyncSocket, withError err: Error?) {

        print("Error: \(Error.self)")
    }
}
```

The server requires that a single JSON object be sent in the form:

```
{"NAME":<name>, "TYPE":"CONNECT"}
```

As you can see in the Connection class code above, that is sent, and when I look at the server output in the Terminal, I see:

```
Connection established
Received: {"NAME":"JERRY","TYPE":"CONNECT"}
{ "TYPE": "CONNECT_RESPONSE" }
```

I now want to parse the response in my app that is coming from the server:

```
{ "TYPE":"CONNECT_RESPONSE" }
```

I've tried what seems like dozens of scenarios, and read numerous Swift entries on Stackoverflow, however nothing is working. When I run the app with the 'Parsed response' print line, I'm just getting 'nil'. Can anyone shed some light? Please?

EDIT:

After attempting the suggested modification,

```
    print("data: \(data)")
    print("parseJSON: \(parseJSON)")
    print("recJSON: \(recJSON)")
    print("sendJSON: \(sendJSON)")
```

...and then testing, I received the following:

```
Connected to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx on port 8889
data: 0 bytes
parseJSON: nil
recJSON: nil
sendJSON: Optional(33 bytes)
Disconnecting
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
let parseJSON = json?["TYPE"]
```

try:

```
let parseJSON = recJson?["TYPE"]
```

Also, try printing both:

```
print(data)
print(recJson)
```

To make sure you are getting a response. Sort of like process of elimination.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Unfortunately, it didn't work, but here was the output: Connected to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx on port 8889
data: 0 bytes
recJSON: nil
parseJSON: nil
Disconnecting
Error: Error

Comment: Are you getting a response from print(data)?

Comment: I'm getting the following: data: 0 bytes

Comment: Ok, so we can see now that its not your receiving json, but your sending json.

Comment: I added the edit to my original question, since it said the edit queue was busy when trying to add to yours. My send seems to be sending properly, and the server is giving the expected response, at least when looking at the Terminal output

Comment: I also just realized I confused the situation. I had tweaked my code in an attempt to make it easily understandable, and put json? instead of recJSON? in the response. I've edited it above. My apologies!

Comment: I do it all the time. lol My laptop is dead but the main problem is that your not getting any data back...

Comment: I'll get back to you later today

Comment: Great, thanks. I'll make an edit to my question to avoid further confusion!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138773/discussion-between-denis-and-quiver13).